# In AngularJS, how can I create a composite variable in my view without it showing?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS in my view I can create composite variables like such:

```
{{shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading}}
```

This is great because I can encapsulate simple UI logic in the UI and leave my controller to deliver functional values, and the composite variable magically updates as its dependencies do.

But the problem is this results in the actual text of the value being shown in my view.

I can do this:

```
<div ng-show="false">{{shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading}}</div>
```

But it smells. I realise I have answered my own question, technically, as I have a working solution, but I feel I must be missing an AngularJS feature, because if they have gone to the effort of allowing such variables then there must be a non-hacky way to not show them.

So, is there a better way to define composite variables in my view and not have them print out?

**Edit**

The two main suggestions are `ng-init` or doing `{{ ' ' || shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading}}`. The third still being my option. I have summarised my testing below:

### 1

```
<div ng-init="shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joshcomley/94627y1u/
This doesn't actually work, because it doesn't update the composite as the dependencies change.

### 2

```
{{ ' ' || shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading }}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joshcomley/8eqb07ph/
This doesn't work either, it just results in an error in AngularJS

### 3

```
<div ng-show="false">{{ shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading }}</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joshcomley/ck2a0syk/
My original way so far is the only way that works and updates as the dependencies change.

Comment: Two correct answers, one with a useful code example and one with a useful link, both delivered at exactly the same time. Time for a coin toss! Six minutes and I can mark as "answered" :D

Comment: I stand corrected; `ng-init` doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddles and you'll see what I want

Comment: I see your point about ng-init.  I don't understand why you would not do this in the controller.

Comment: I understand it is considered bad practice, but in my own architecture I made my own decision to keep the controller delivering functions and functional state information. I'm just seeing how it goes, and I like it thus far. I am finding that it is keeping an even greater separation of concerns, as opposed to having the controller maintain 100% UI-centric variables. Doing that means the controller has to know about the view, and I don't like that.

Comment: @joshcomley I've updated my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: Hi @AlexSzabó, thanks, I checked your update; you still have the `{{' ' || shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading}}` answer in there at the top, which I can't get to work (which makes sense because angular will evaluate the left part and never reach the right).

Comment: @joshcomley I've updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8eqb07ph/1/ and proposed `{{(bothTicked = (first && second)) ? '' : ''}}` or a hidden span that uses the regular syntax

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you are looking for ng-init.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

I have never used it.  The documentation says more or less, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

use ng-init:

```
<div ng-init="shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading">
    <!-- somewhere in here, you can now use the shouldShow variable -->
</div>
```

However, be aware that it is best practice to put that type of logic in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
{{' ' || shouldShow = !isNew && !uploading}}
```

I have also updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8eqb07ph/1/)

I've added a version that uses a `<span>` element

```
<span ng-hide="true">
  {{bothTicked = (first && second)}}
</span>
```

And another solution that "scrapes on hacky":

```
{{(bothTicked = (first && second)) ? '' : ''}}
```

But nevertheless, it works.

Comment: Nice :) I do like that, as it's less to write than `ng-init`, yet I still feel it's just scraping on "hacky"